# QtCreator/qmake extra targets not being run

Tags: qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qmake subdirs project and in the top level .pro file, I specify an extra target like so:

```
gruntbuild.target = gruntbuild
gruntbuild.commands = grunt --gruntfile $$PWD/Gruntfile.js

gui.depends = lib gruntbuild

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += gruntbuild
```

I can see in the resulting `Makefile` that a `gruntbuild` target is correctly added, however the `all` target does not reference it, so `gruntbuild` is not being run when `jom.exe` is called by QtCreator.

Do I need to add an extra command to ensure the target is run?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as easy as adding `gui`to `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`. In other words, use

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += gui gruntbuild
```

The reason is that you have to "export" the modified `gui`-target to the Makefile too. This will append another depend for the target, but that is apparently legal.